# How can I test Temporal code that uses `activity.GetLogger(ctx)`?

Tags: go, temporal-workflow

Say I have a function in an activity that looks like this:

```golang
func logSomething(ctx context.Context) {
  log := activity.GetLogger(ctx)
  log.Info("logging something")
}
```

Now if I want to call that function from a test like this:

```golang
logSomething(context.Background())
```

It will fail with:

```
test panicked: getActivityOutboundInterceptor: Not an activity context
```

How do I get a proper activity context in a test? I tried tacking on an activity interceptor onto the context like this:

```golang
var Logger logger.Logger = logger.NewLogger(zapcore.DebugLevel)
var TemporalLogger = logur.LoggerToKV(Logger)

type fakeTemporalActivityOutBoundInterceptor struct {
    interceptor.ActivityOutboundInterceptorBase
}

func (f *fakeTemporalActivityOutBoundInterceptor) GetLogger(_ temporal_workflow.Context) temporal_log.Logger {
    return TemporalLogger
}


ctx := context.WithValue(
    context.Background(),
    "activityInterceptor",
    &fakeTemporalActivityOutBoundInterceptor{},
)
```

But `"activityInterceptor"` is not recognized as equal to [`activityInterceptorContextKey`](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-go/blob/v1.17.0/internal/internal_activity.go#L155), so I still get the same error :/

I'm using [`temporalio v1.17.0`](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-go/tree/v1.17.0)

Comment: looks a bit like you're using context as a service locator. The context you're creating has the fake under a key of type `string`, whereas your activity package will use a `activityInterceptorContextKey` (shorten that name for the love of God - it's not exported, so `activity` in the `activity` package is just noise!). The two are not interchangeable. That's the whole reason for unexported types used as value keys like this. Just inject dependencies, service-locator stuff like this is a PITA.

Comment: That said, the quick-fix would be to add helper functions (that you'd only use in testing, so it's more code smell) that allow you to pre-load the context object -> in activity package have a `SetLogger(ctx context.Context, l Logger)` function, that just `return context.WithValue(ctx, loggerKey, l)`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write a helper function that checks if your code is being executed within a Temporal activity context or within a non temporal context and then returns a Temporal logger accordingly.

```golang
func GetLogger(ctx context.Context) log.Logger {
    if activity.IsActivity(ctx) {
        return activity.GetLogger(ctx)
    }

    return log.NewStructuredLogger(slog.Default())
}
```

`log.Logger` is just an [interface](https://pkg.go.dev/go.temporal.io/sdk/log#Logger):

```
Logger interface {
        Debug(msg string, keyvals ...interface{})
        Info(msg string, keyvals ...interface{})
        Warn(msg string, keyvals ...interface{})
        Error(msg string, keyvals ...interface{})
    }
```

so you could also implement your own if thats what you want.